# Converting grammars to the most efficient parser

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

Is there an online algorithm which converts certain grammar to the most efficient parser possible?

For example: SLR/LR(k) such as k>=0

Comment: It depends on the type of grammar. Context-sensitive grammars are often more difficult to parse than context-free grammars.

Comment: Also, it's possible to simplify context-free grammars by converting them to [Greibach normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach_normal_form) or [Kuroda normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuroda_normal_form).

Comment: @AndersonGreen It's not context-sensitive, the grammars I'm checking are simple

Comment: If I remember what Frank de Remer taught me 41 years ago correctly, the actual LR parsing algorithm is the same for LR, LALR, and SLR. Only the table is different.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne:  actually, the tables can be the same; it is how much of the tables the algorithm looks at that matters and what it does with it.   For instance, LR(0) ignores the lookahead sets.  It is interesting to note that you can build GLR parsers just fine using the same tables.  (DeRemer is pretty smart so I'm not quite sure what he told you).

Comment: @MarquisofLorne: All the LR algorithm variations do have the same core algorithm of push an token on the stack, then do any reductions indicated by tables, repeat.  Maybe that's what he meant.

Answer (score 4):

For the class of grammars you are discussing (xLR(k)), they are all linear time anyway, and it is impossible to do sublinear time if you have to examine every character.

If you insist on optimizing parse time, you should get a very fast LR parsing engine.  LRStar used to be the cat's meow on this topic, but the guy behind it got zero reward from the world of "I want it for free" and pulled all instances of it off the net.  You can settle for Bison.

Frankly most of your parsing time will be determined by how fast your parser can process individual characters, e.g., the lexer.   Tune that first and you may discover there's no need to tune the parser.

Comment: While it may or may not be *pragmatic,* it is *possible* to get sublinear time. Combining radix-tree (of the possible catch phrases in the parser's current context) with bitmasking it is possible to filter 4 bytes or 8 bytes at a time (or really k bytes). The results of each check contain information enabling the next check to "skip ahead" in the frame. It is also possible to use parallel processing in such a way that sibling "cursors" sparsely profile the data ahead, to inform the actual parsing.

Comment: I couldn't quite fit it, but I realize we're in the context of "no context"/ context free -- but you can still have a trie of all valid escape terms in real life without altering the class of grammar. That trade off slightly ties the parser's complexity to the design of your resulting structure, which defines what you are looking for in a context free way, rather than the document.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could do that.  Never seen anybody actually do it in practice.  As you said, no pragmatic... just not worth the extra effort.

Comment: Yeah absolutely it would be quite the hassle for parsing. Just a knowledge artifact of image filtering haha.

Answer (score 0):

First let's distinguish LR(k) grammars and LR(k) languages. A grammar may not be LR(1), but let's say, for example, LR(2). But the *language* it generates must have an LR(1) grammar -- and for that matter, it must have an LALR(1) grammar. The table size for such a grammar is essentially the same as for SLR(1) and is more powerful (all SLR(1) grammars are LALR(1) but not vice versa). So, there is really no reason not to use an LALR(1) parser generator if you are looking to do LR parsing.

Since parsing represents only a fraction of the compilation time in modern compilers when lexical analysis and code generation that contains peephole and global optimizations are taken into consideration, I would just pick a tool considering its entire set of features. You should also remember that one parser generator may take a little longer than another to analyze a grammar and to generate the parsing tables. But once that job is done, the table-driven parsing algorithm that will run in the actual compiler thousands of times should not vary significantly from one parser generator to another.

As far as tools for converting arbitrary grammars to LALR(1), for example (in theory this *can* be done), you could do a Google search (I have *not* done this). But since semantics are tied to the productions, I would want to have complete control over the grammar being used for parsing and would probably eschew such conversion tools.